# Custom 403 Error Page not loading CSS

Tags: html, ubuntu, apache2, http-status-code-403

I am having a problem whereby my Custom 403 Error Page does not seem to load the CSS file, I have a Custom 404 Error Page that works perfectly well and I have the EXACT same code on my 403 page with just a few adjustments to the Header and Body Text. I am running Apache2 on Ubuntu.

Thanks

Harry

Comment: Based on what you're saying, the few adjustments you made may have broken the code, if you can provide some code we can have a better idea of what your problem is.

Comment: I dont think it was though, All I changed was the 404 to 403 in the header and then "Sorry, the requested page does not exist." to "Sorry, you do not have permission to access that page" I even duplicated the 404 error page and changed the name so it would think it was the 403 error page but there was no difference

Comment: Is the 403 page in the same directory as the 404? are the id's and classes named the same?

Comment: Yep, and what do you mean by the id's and classes?

Comment: The name of the elements in your html, make sure the classes (class="you_class") are the same as in the 404 page which is used in the CSS. Again, if you can provide some code, we can better assist.

Comment: Oh right yeh, they are exactly the same, what code would you want me to provide you with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An old question, but I had the same one just now. I figured out a way, and since this was not fully answered, here's my 2 cents.

Use the full url to call the css file. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

A 403 Error means file that user tried to access is forbidden. Instead the 403 file is returned.

However the CSS file that you are trying to access in your 403 is probably also forbidden therefore no styles file to use.

Try placing the styles in the 403 file itself.

Comment: How would the CSS file be forbidden?

Comment: Why not? it could be in a directory/folder that is forbidden, or for any other reason why 403 was triggered at the first place. Trying placing the CSS in the file itself to see if it is picked up.

Comment: I have many different CSS elements that make up the HTML document, I will just try and make some rubbish HTML code that gets to the point

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the exact url of your CSS code that you want to adopt in your html page. for example if you use a css file in a folder called CSS in the same directory of your HTML file, replace the following example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/yourFile.css" />
```

with this one:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://yoursite/CSS/yourFile.css" />
```

same rule goes for uploading images and SVGs and fonts...